# Informations about building using Place Search

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm actually working on the Google Maps Place Search API and I try to get some informations that I can see on the Google Maps App.

[Google Maps for Android screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CgwY.png)

[When I click on my position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvzxc.png)

I want "Gare de Lyon Part-Dieu", with its place_id. It's the name of the "global" building.

When I do a nearbysearch with this position and a precise accuracy, I just get places like "LA CROISSANTERIE" or "Relay". Establishments in this buildings.

Is it possible to get informations about the building ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get this building by using its `place_id` instead of coordinates. What I mean is get the place_id of **Gare de Lyon Part-Dieu** with the help of this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/place-id).

So this is the place_id of **Gare de Lyon Part-Dieu** (`ChIJKWSv_WLq9EcR-FEoq1JxCW4`)

Now, we can retrieve place details using the place ID.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJKWSv_WLq9EcR-FEoq1JxCW4&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

With this request, you can now get the available information in Google Maps database about Gare de Lyon Part-Dieu place like opening/closing hours and etc.

Hope it helps you.